# How to control Get-MailboxFolderStatistics output language?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, pssnapin

I want Chinese,But it output english folderName like "Inbox" instead of "收件箱".It occurred when request it one by one.I put it into a http request.When i requested it one by one,the problem occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Set-MailboxRegionalConfiguration -Identity username -Language zh-CN -LocalizeDefaultFolderName
```